# Node.JS async.parallel confusion | what is returned by async.map

Tags: javascript, node.js, async.js

There are **50** folders in both **OneDrive** and **GDrive**, each folder contains **500** files.
`onedriveUrls` and `gdriveUrls` are arrays of `length` **50** containing links to those folders respectively.

**Confusion!** Following code is expected to run parallel at 2 levels, first at `async.parallel` and second at `async.map`, Is it a correct code or `async.map` should be wrapped in `setTimeout` to ensure all levels are running parallel?

```
async.parallel({
        onedrive: function(callback){
            async.map(onedriveUrls, request, function(err, results) {
                if (err) throw(err);          // handle error
                callback(null,results);  
            });
        },
        gdrive: function(callback){                
            async.map(gdriveUrls, request, function(err, results) {
                if (err) throw(err);          // handle error
                callback(null,results);  
            });
        }
    },
    function(err, results) {
        // results is now equals to: {onedrive: [array_of_length_x], gdrive: [array_of_length_y]}
    });
```

Also what is returned by async.map -- promise or what?

Happy Helping!

Comment: *`throw err`* doesn't look like "*handle error*"…

Comment: The only thing I'd change (beyond `throw(err)`, possibly) is using `async.mapSeries` so you don't send hundreds of requests to your network service at once.

Comment: its not case of my server, google can handle me that much requests

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it a correct code or async.map should be wrapped in setTimeout to ensure all levels are running parallel?

No. `request` is expected to be asynchronous, and everything is fine. Wrapping anything in a `setTimeout` doesn't help.

> Also what is returned by async.map -- promise or what?

Nothing. [`map`](https://github.com/caolan/async#map) returns `undefined` like most other asynchronous functions, it only calls its callback with the results array.

---

Btw, you should simplify your code to

```
async.parallel({
    onedrive: function(callback) {
        async.map(onedriveUrls, request, callback);
    },
    gdrive: function(callback) {
        async.map(gdriveUrls, request, callback);
    }
}, function(err, results) {
    …
});
```